# get the time from the time server and update the mobile device time

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, cordova

I tried to find the specific answer to my question but i didn't find the relevant help.

Actually i want to get the time and date  from the time/date server (could be any ) .and update the time and date of our mobile(android/iPhone/etc) . i want to do this thing in java script.i tried different type of codes to get time and date from server in java script but that's not working . 
 DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
That is giving me invalid time error.
if somebody give me any reference or specific help i shall be very thankful to them. 
Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual Date on javascript:

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

To set it on the device, you'll need to create a plugin for phonegap build to do the platform specifics on setting the system datetime. Take a look here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/developer_contributing_plugins.md.html